# What is the default set of packages installed with Trusty?

Tags: 14.04

Where can I find a list of all the packages that get installed by default with Ubuntu 14.04?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Do you want explanation for all 1744 default packages or something in particular? You can find the full list [here](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04.6-desktop-amd64.manifest) for Ubuntu 14.04.6 LTS.

Comment: Nooo this is what I needed! Was searching and searching but to no avail! Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Ubuntu comes with many [preinstalled applications](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Applications). See the link I provided. Those applications are recommended by ubunt. This is a cutting of that site:

1. [Accessories](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AccessoriesApplications) – Various useful utilities.
2. [Games](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Games) – Information on games written for Ubuntu Linux, as well as
   how to run Windows games in Ubuntu.
3. [Graphics](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/GraphicsApplications) – Software for creating and manipulating images.
4. [Photo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Photos) – Software for viewing and editing photos.
5. [Internet](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InternetApplications) – Network applications like web browsers, email clients,
   and instant messengers.
6. [Other](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OtherSoftware) – Software for business, science, medicine, engineering, and
   other professional disciplines.
7. [Office](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OfficeApplications) – Software such as word processors, spreadsheet,
   presentation, and database applications.
8. [Productivity](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ProductivityApplications) – Software such as organizers, schedulers, planners and
   management applications.
9. [Servers and Web Applications](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Servers) – Software for creating websites,
   teleconferencing servers, learning management systems, and other web
   applications.
10. [Sound and Video](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundVideoDefault) – Software for playing, ripping, and burning music
    and videos.
11. [Multimedia](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Multimedia) – Software for playing and editing sound and video.
12. [System Tools](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SystemTools) – Software for configuring and managing Ubuntu.

Comment: The applications you refer to are *available* on Ubuntu, but it does not make them *preinstalled applications*. There is no [preinstalled LAMP stack](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Servers), for instance. This is also why the page you link offers installation guides.